# How do you re-sign an IPA file without a Apple developer account

Tags: ios, ipa

I'm testing an iOS app for a client in UAT and they want us to re-sign the IPA. How can I resign it without an apple developer account. Is it required to have a  provisioning profile and certificate to be used for re-sign.

Comment: Run `openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout server.key -out certificateSigningRequest.csr` command to generate a CSR (certificate signing request). Upload that to the developer portal and download the certificate from the portal (on MacOS, you can use Keychain to generate the CSR instead of OpenSSL if you wish). Now you have a certificate and you can generate the provisioning profile on the dev portal. Now use python's `isign` to sign the IPA or use `fastlane` to resign it.

Comment: Thanks @Brandon . Is there a way to re-sign it without having a provisioning profile in Apple, because i don't have a dev profile in Apple and it takes a while to get it approved.

Comment: There is no way to do it without a provisioning profile. If you jailbreak it, you will be able to install unsigned IPA's so long as you install `AppSync` from Cydia and you will install the app via SSH (command-line or WinSCP). IE: If you jailbreak, it can be done yes.

Btw, have you thought of just installing MacOS in a VM (VMWare or Virtual Box)? That also works too.

Comment: Thanks @Brandon.I've installed MacOS on a VM but I don't have a apple developer account. So can't get a provisioning profile. Will try via AppSync.

Comment: Oh.. then you can create a project, plug in a phone, get Xcode to automatically generate a profile. Find the profile on your computer and use IPAResigner or anything you wish to sign your IPA using that profile.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it required to have a provisioning profile and certificate to be used for re-sign.

Yes. You cannot do any kind of distribution without a paid developer account.

Comment: Thanks @matt. If I jailbreak the mobile, will I be able to install the .IPA without re-signing it.